# Agregar un AND en la Funcion SI en Excel

Tags: excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear una funcion en la cual diga:

```
SI porcentaje_cruce >= 80 Y Claificación_final >= 50% entonces 2000 si no es 0.
```

Comment: Y que probaste hasta ahora?

Comment: No tengo idea de como poner un AND dentro la funcion SI, no he probado nada

Comment: Hay una funcion que se llama AND...

Comment: claro la funcion Y pero, no se como meterla dentro de la funcion SI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El uso de la función `Y` o `AND` en inglés va dentro de la función principal que en este caso es `SI` o `IF` en inglés

Entonces tu fórmula debería quedar de este modo

```
=SI(Y(C6>=80, D6>=50), 2000, 0)
```

Como vamos a meter dentro del `SI` una comparación doble entonces ambas las separamos únicamente por una coma

*Considere válido responderte por que tienes en tu pregunta la idea de como sería la comparación en pseudocódigo*

Answer (score 0):

Te lo explico con un ejemplo con la **Función SI y**

En la fórmula siguiente, la función Y en excel, está anidada dentro de la prueba lógica de la función SI.

La la función Y devuelve VERDADERO, cuando las dos prueba lógica se cumplen y se descuenta el 10% de la cantidad en la columna B; de lo contrario, no se aplica ningún descuento y el valor de la columna B se repite en la columna D. [ver mas ejemplos](https://siempreexcel.com/funcion-y-en-excel/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]